# How to implement Selective error retry in osb for http backend service

Tags: http, error-handling, oracle12c, osb

Im calling a http service from my pipeline and i want to retry all error except for 4xx series.But when i give retry count as 3 all error are getting retried. Is there any way so that i can tune my os service to only retry non 4xx errors.

Comment: please add your script example here we will be able to help with

Comment: I have implemneted the retry by configuring the retry count in business service.

Answer (score 0):

if you use OOTB retry in business service ,it will retry for all the error codes..You can try to call the http business service from a stage and using a stage error handler call the http service from a while loop.